# What's the correct architectual pattern for storing object references in Java?

Tags: java

In a Java Application you many times face a situation, when you want to store all **Object References** for newly created **objects**, for example to retrieve it by a specific **key** later. Key can be any of this object's **fields**. There are many **Collections**, that are suitable for it:

- **List**
- **Map**
- **Set**
- etc...

All of them have one **similar thing**, if you want to use it, you have to put it inside a **variable**. **Static variables** are bad and should not be used, so **variable** also needs a **class** that will hold **it**. How should you name a **class**, that is responsible for **storing** **references** to other class's **objects**? Also, is it a good practice to put a **method** for **retrieving** a single **reference** from this "manager" **class**? Is there some way to automatically generate this kind of **class**, by its key?

Comment: Are you talking about class names or instance names?  Because the class is already named: to refer to a ```List``` the class (interface) of the list is ```List```, or you can use ```Collection```.  If you're talking about creating your own container classes, then you should name them by what they do, just as List, Map, etc., (which are actually interfaces) are named to reflect the facilities they offer.

Comment: I meant a **class** that is responsible for holding and retrieving all created **objects** of some other class.

Comment: So if you have some class ```Thing``` then there is an object somewhere that knows about every single ```Thing``` in the program?

Comment: Yes, it some cases it is necessary.

Comment: OK, I get it. The talk of Java collection classes confused me; those are just ways you could implement this particular object (right?).  What I'd call it depends on what it does.  If it's just a way to locate all Things, I'd maybe call it a ThingMap or a ThingDirectory.  If it has some sort of controlling action on Things, I'd maybe go for ThingManager or ThingController.  My naming is more concerned with what role it is taking than just the fact that it knows every Thing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. One more question. Is it a good practice to make this **ThingManager** also responsible for new objects creation, like factory or it would break **single responsibility principle**?

Comment: This [object pool pattern](https://www.javatpoint.com/object-pool-pattern) might be over-kill, but seems to meet your stated requirements of "... holding and retrieval of all created objects".